# Button Event for Touch Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am going to develop a `HTML5` website for Kiosk which supports `point` and `drag&drop`. There are some buttons or images on the website for user interaction. Unlike a mouse click, actions are finger `touchs` on the screen. Should I handle `click` or `mousedown` event for better response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start from reading about [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events).

Also please consider [fast click](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library to eliminate 300ms delay.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. Both links are useful. For the page of touch events, the new event handling is disabled in Firefox 24 due to a bug. Since my Kiosk runs on Desktop computers, it impacted. For fast click library, does it mean disabling double click for fast response?